# Mapping does not work with some characters in KeyRemap4Macbook

Tags: keybindings

I want to map `Option+Dot` and `Option+Comma` to word-by-word movement in KeyRemap4Macbook. `Option+Dot` works but `Option+Comma` does not. Also using any other character such as W, V etc. instead of Comma does not work. They simply put the symbols normally mapped in keylayout file.

Here are the mapping items:

```
<item>
    <name>word movement right</name>
    <identifier>private.wordright</identifier>
    <autogen>
        --KeyToKey--
        KeyCode::COMMA,ModifierFlag::OPTION_L,
        KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT,ModifierFlag::OPTION_L
    </autogen>
</item>
<item>
    <name>word movement by option + dot</name>
    <identifier>private.wordmovement</identifier>
    <autogen>
        --KeyToKey--
        KeyCode::DOT,ModifierFlag::OPTION_L,
        KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT,ModifierFlag::OPTION_L
    </autogen>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause of the problem. I have Turkish keyboard layout installed. The place of character `comma` corresponds to the place of character `B` in Turkish keyboard layout. The KeyCode definitions requires the character in the US keyboard layout.